# Tensorflow 1.x Items of feature_columns must be a _FeatureColumn. Given type is List

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, linear-regression

I'm working on a machine learning project using TensorFlow 1.15 in which I'm creating the feature columns using `tf.feature_column` but stuck on an error for that.

Here's how I'm defining the `feature columns`:

```
# Define feature columns

is_male = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('is_male', vocabulary_list=['False', 'True'])
plurality = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('plurality', vocabulary_list=['Single(1)', 'Twins(2)', 'Triplets(3)', 'Quadruplets(4)', 'Quintuplets(5)'])
wide_columns = [is_male, plurality]
mother_age = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="mother_age", shape=10)
gestation_weeks = tf.feature_column.numeric_column(key="gestation_weeks", shape=10)
deep_columns = [mother_age,gestation_weeks]
feature_cols = [wide_columns, deep_columns]
```

and here's the exact error I'm getting:

> ValueError: Items of feature_columns must be a _FeatureColumn. Given (type ): [VocabularyListCategoricalColumn(key='is_male', vocabulary_list=('False', 'True'), dtype=tf.string, default_value=-1, num_oov_buckets=0), VocabularyListCategoricalColumn(key='plurality', vocabulary_list=('Single(1)', 'Twins(2)', 'Triplets(3)', 'Quadruplets(4)', 'Quintuplets(5)'), dtype=tf.string, default_value=-1, num_oov_buckets=0)].

Answer (score 0):

I think that `feature_cols` contains two lists so you're passing `feature_cols = [[is_male, plurality], [mother_age, gestation_weeks]]`. I believe what you want to do is `feature_cols = wide_columns + deep_columns`.